# Gradle docker build hangs indefinitely

Tags: docker, gradle

My build works randomly and hangs randomly even when run with exactly the same parameters. It's always getting stuck after my copy task (some parts replaced with )

```
task createDocker(group: '<placeholder>', type: Docker) {
    push = true
    dockerfile = file(stageDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/Dockerfile")
    project.group = "<placeholder>"
    applicationName = "<placeholder>-clusterservice"
    tagVersion = "${project.version}"

    doFirst {
        println ("Copying Dockerfile to staging area:" + stageDir.getAbsolutePath())
        copy {
            from "${project.projectDir}/src/main/docker/"
            include "**/*"
            into stageDir
        }

        println ("Getting artifact")
        copy {
            from "$distDir/${war.baseName}-${war.version}.war"
            rename "${war.baseName}-${war.version}.war", "clusterservice.war"
            into stageDir
        }
    }
}
```

I ran it with debug flags and this is what it looks like when it works:

```
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:49.730 [QUIET] [system.out] Getting artifact
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:50.041 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute doFirst {} action for :clusterservice:createDocker'
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:50.041 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute doFirst {} action for :clusterservice:createDocker' completed
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:50.041 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute build for :clusterservice:createDocker' started
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:50.041 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Setting up staging directory.
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:50.041 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Creating Dockerfile from file /opt/teamcity/agent/work/7fe8da50bfc4c49f/clusterservice/build-gradle/docker/Dockerfile.
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:50.045 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Determining image tag: <placeholder>/<placeholder>-clusterservice:8.23.0-SNAPSHOT
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:25:50.045 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Using the native docker binary.
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:26:05.213 [QUIET] [system.out] Sending build context to Docker daemon    194MB
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:26:05.213 [QUIET] [system.out] Step 1/33 : FROM <placeholder>/tomcat-openjre8:8.5.40
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:26:05.213 [QUIET] [system.out]  ---> aa259d3bf785
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:26:05.213 [QUIET] [system.out] Step 2/33 : LABEL MAINTAINER 'dev@<placeholder>.com'
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:26:05.213 [QUIET] [system.out]  ---> Using cache
[16:26:15] :     [Step 1/1] 16:26:05.213 [QUIET] [system.out]  ---> 14bff4363c7f
...
```

Then it continues to build normally with no errors!

Here's the a failing build run on the exact same machine and exact same parameters

```
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:37.030 [QUIET] [system.out] Getting artifact
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:38.608 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute doFirst {} action for :clusterservice:createDocker'
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:38.609 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute doFirst {} action for :clusterservice:createDocker' completed
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:38.609 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute build for :clusterservice:createDocker' started
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:38.609 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Setting up staging directory.
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:38.612 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Creating Dockerfile from file /opt/teamcity/agent/work/7fe8da50bfc4c49f/clusterservice/build-gradle/docker/Dockerfile.
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:38.645 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Determining image tag: <placeholder>/<placeholder>-clusterservice:8.23.0-SNAPSHOT
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:52:38.645 [INFO] [se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask] Using the native docker binary.
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:03.859 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] 
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:03.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33737138176, Free: 26021330944}
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:03.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33737138176, Free: 26021330944}
[15:53:03] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:03.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1908932608, Committed: 1186463744}
[15:53:08] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:08.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33737138176, Free: 26022682624}
[15:53:08] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:08.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33737138176, Free: 26022682624}
[15:53:08] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:08.859 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1908932608, Committed: 1186463744}
[15:53:11] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:11.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
[15:53:11] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:11.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[15:53:11] :     [Step 1/1] 15:53:11.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
...
```

It doesn't error out, and the health check repeats and runs indefinitely (I let it run over 2 hours) and it just continues to hang without any errors. I have no clue what's wrong with it, the build runs completely fine if I run the commands manually. If it works the build takes around 7 minutes or so. Please help.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?... have been dealing with this for like a year

Comment: @Toofy maybe you found a solution? It seems that I'm having the same issues.

Comment: @dephinera unfortunately no. In the end I found that it was an issue with the specific gradle plugin we were using and upon checking their github page the project hadn't been maintained in over 2 years. (I think it was this one https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker).. so in the end I just rewrote everything in bash and have no more issues now

Answer (score 0):

It appears that development on the project for this specific docker gradle plugin has been abandoned.

If you check the issue on this github page here https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker/issues/119 and here https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker/issues/37 you will see that this issue was reported years ago but no fix has ever been merged in.

There are other gradle docker plugins that are available that are a bit more active in development which you could use. This one https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin comes to mind.

Personally in the end after getting incredibly fed up with all of this I just rewrote everything in a bash script and used gradle to call said script in order to do my necessary docker configuration.